# Jira Query Language, search EPIC key using corresponding story

Tags: jira, jql

I am trying to get the Epic issue key using the issue key of one of its stories.
What would be the query that gives in this result.

Thanks.

---update---

Let's suppose there is an EPIC : PG-01, and a story which is linked to it PG-02, I tried searching with "Epic Link" in ("PG-02"), doesn't give the expected result

Comment: What did you try already ?

Comment: Let's suppose there is an EPIC : PG-01, and a story which is linked to it PG-02, I tried searching with "Epic Link" in ("PG-02"), doesn't give the expected result

Comment: I think you use the epic link filter to return stories within a particular epic - so in your example you could use `"Epic Link" = PG-01`

Comment: This is a restriction, I want to use the story key to get the Epic key, what you've suggested is the other way round.

Comment: I believe that is how the epic link criteria works, I am not aware of a way to do what what you are after in the standard product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know of a way to do this with JIRA out of the box, but the [Script Runner add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview) does provide a JQL function that supports this. You can use a query like this one:

```
issueFunction in epicsOf("key = MYPROJECT-2")
```

Documentation is available [here](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/4.3.9/jira/jql-functions.html#_epicsof).